# How to get data from a nested JSON (kotlin, android studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have following JSON:

```
{
"message": {
    "AmountTotal": 0.0,
    "dateCort": "2020-03-30",
    "deliveries": [
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "4498748666",
                "trackingid": "ab5cdce3-55a8-4c76-8ac7-f60c3b59a21a",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Notas:EDIFICIO CON REJAS CORTINA BLANCA TOCAR TIMBRE SOLO Cobro: No Monto: 2499.03 Referencia Calles:ROSA VENUS Y ROSA VERDE Referencia:ENFRENTE CLUB DE LEONES Recibe: GARCIA MARTHA YOLANDA CC:uniform_alexa@yahoo.com.mx Ordvta:11708312 Remesa:430164",
                "company": "Inova",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "ROSA VULCANO NO 57 PB , MOLINO DE ROSAS, ÁLVARO OBREGÓN, Mexico, Mexico, Mexico, 01470",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.3710457",
                "long": "-99.2016972"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "GARCIA MARTHA YOLANDA",
                "emailClient": "uniform_alexa@yahoo.com.mx",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "ROSA VULCANO NO 57 PB , MOLINO DE ROSAS, ÁLVARO OBREGÓN, Mexico, Mexico, Mexico, 01470",
                "latitud": "19.3710457",
                "longitud": "-99.2016972"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "864952497",
                "trackingid": "edff79c4-17c5-4058-a998-eeeba8ae6886",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Notas:FACHADA ROSA DESPINTADO TRES NIVELES SEGUNDO NIVEL ENTRAR POR LA MISCELANEA Cobro: No Monto: 1771.84 Referencia Calles:EJE 1 RAYON  Y ECUADOR  Referencia:ENTRADA MISCELANEA CHAVEZ FRENTE A UNA CALLE DEL MERCADO DE  Recibe: ESTEVEZ CATALINA  CC:katystvz2609@gmail.com Ordvta:11708399 Remesa:430164",
                "company": "Inova",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "COMONFORT NO 15 DEP 206  , CENTRO (ÁREA 2), CUAUHTÉMOC, Mexico, Mexico, Mexico, 06010",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.4428603",
                "long": "-99.1350222"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "ESTEVEZ CATALINA ",
                "emailClient": "katystvz2609@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "COMONFORT NO 15 DEP 206  , CENTRO (ÁREA 2), CUAUHTÉMOC, Mexico, Mexico, Mexico, 06010",
                "latitud": "19.4428603",
                "longitud": "-99.1350222"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "882507224",
                "trackingid": "c8ac11e9-118b-411e-9593-5ee4ddcb94c2",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "#id | Cobro: Si, cobrar: 105 | Recibe: Diego Hernández | Recolecta con: Diego Hernández",
                "company": "99minutos",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 105.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "zarco , 06600,False,,06600,MEX",
                "phoneSender": "5555555555",
                "lat": "19.4276061",
                "long": "-99.16083719999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-02-11",
                "contactName": "Diego Hernández",
                "emailClient": "Diego@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "5555555555",
                "address": "zarco , 06600,False,,06600,MEX",
                "latitud": "19.4276061",
                "longitud": "-99.16083719999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "399068610",
                "trackingid": "32e738db-df7b-4e37-a162-86c4cc00d2b1",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "#id | Cobro: Si, cobrar: 0.0 |  Recibe: Destino | Recolecta con: Destino | Mismo dia bike",
                "company": "99minutos",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Bolivar 97   Centro (Area 1)  Cuauhtemoc MX-CMX 06000 Mexico, ,,06000,Mexico",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.4187269",
                "long": "-99.1406159"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-02-11",
                "contactName": "Destino",
                "emailClient": "destino@pakke.mx",
                "phoneClient": "9898898989",
                "address": "Bolivar 97   Centro (Area 1)  Cuauhtemoc MX-CMX 06000 Mexico, ,,06000,Mexico",
                "latitud": "19.4187269",
                "longitud": "-99.1406159"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "2253324354",
                "trackingid": "8de98a5d-7f90-4d6e-b9ed-27014672e0be",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden : A0212936 | Se recolecta con : VirginMobile | Entregara : RAMIRO PACHECO | Cobro : Si | Producto : Grande Ilimitado | Cantidad : 1 | Transacction Id : B2C202001180179593 | Referencia : DENTRO DEL MERCADO FRANCISCO VILLA | Monto a cobrar : 149.00 ",
                "company": "Virgin Mobile",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 149.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Nogal 29 135 , Viveros de Xalostoc, Ecatepec de Morelos, México, Mexico, 55340",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.52044",
                "long": "-99.07903189999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "RAMIRO PACHECO",
                "emailClient": "pachecohola220403@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "Nogal 29 135 , Viveros de Xalostoc, Ecatepec de Morelos, México, Mexico, 55340",
                "latitud": "19.52044",
                "longitud": "-99.07903189999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "9710980716",
                "trackingid": "08e42f5e-55a6-4e53-b926-c9fd6d77f721",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden : A0212922 | Se recolecta con : VirginMobile | Entregara : MANUEL RAMOS GUARNEROS | Cobro : Si | Producto : Portabilidad | Cantidad : 1 | Transacction Id : B2C202001180179590 | Referencia : ENTRE LAS CALLES CIELITO LINDO Y AMANECER RANCHERO CASA DE DOS PISOS, ZAGUÁN BLANCO FACHADA COLOR MELÓN  MANUEL RAMOS | Monto a cobrar : 0.02 ",
                "company": "Virgin Mobile",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.02,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "La Pajarera 156  , Benito Juárez (La Aurora), Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl, México, Mexico, 57000",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.4030357",
                "long": "-99.0193204"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "MANUEL RAMOS GUARNEROS",
                "emailClient": "jared991@yahoo.com.mx",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "La Pajarera 156  , Benito Juárez (La Aurora), Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl, México, Mexico, 57000",
                "latitud": "19.4030357",
                "longitud": "-99.0193204"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "2686211063",
                "trackingid": "f45d905a-15c9-442e-8462-7ba2a7bdbd43",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden: 302c7d82-5970-4e93-b1fb-e632ce9eae61 | Se recolecta con: MARIANA GALVEZ | Entregar a: MAURICIO VILLASENOR | Cobro: No | PROTEÍNA, Recoger el dia: 2020-01-10, Telefono Remitente: 5574639803, entre calles: na, referencia exterior: na, Telefono destinatario: 5554065350",
                "company": "Envioclick ",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "seneca 55, POLANCO II, Miguel Hidalgo, Miguel Hidalgo, DISTRITO FEDERAL, Mexico, 11550",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.4341866",
                "long": "-99.2024802"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-09",
                "contactName": "MAURICIO VILLASENOR",
                "emailClient": "ANDREA_S04@HOTMAIL.COM",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "ricardo palmerin 71, guadalupe inn, Alvaro Obregon, Alvaro Obregon, DISTRITO FEDERAL, Mexico, 01020",
                "latitud": "19.3582169",
                "longitud": "-99.1881362"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "6685254369",
                "trackingid": "fbacfe2b-b84c-4faf-8dc1-0c15cb723d9c",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "Orden: 17e869d7-5dac-4431-9a16-d432836db276 | Se recolecta con: Hokana Hokana | Entregar a: Alfonso Hidalgo | Cobro: No | TA03,Y12, Recoger el dia: 2020-01-13, Telefono Remitente: 5555555555, entre calles: na, referencia exterior: na",
                "company": "Envioclick ",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "PROL HIDALGO A 62 , San Pedro Barrientos, Tlalnepantla de Baz, Tlalnepantla de Baz, EDO. DE MEXICO, Mexico, 54010",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.5866172",
                "long": "-99.19436879999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-13",
                "contactName": "Jafra Online",
                "emailClient": "",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "SEC 19 MZ 33 LT 34 , Sec 19 mz 33 lt 34, Ecatepec de Morelos, Ecatepec de Morelos, EDO. DE MEXICO, Mexico, 55100",
                "latitud": "19.4968732",
                "longitud": "-99.72326729999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "8403987746",
                "trackingid": "1f1d6118-6b19-42db-823d-85979ed930fe",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "Orden: 4245825 | Se recolecta con: Antonio Garcia | Entregar a: MARGARITA INOJOSA ALVAREZ | Cobro: No | FACHADA VERDE PORTON BLANCO DE 3 NIVELES EN LA ESQ HAY UNA TIENDA Y ENFRENTE TAMBIEN",
                "company": "Cv Directo",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "10"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Av. de la Naranja 1C, Fracc. Industrial Alce Blanco, Naucalpan de Juarez, Naucalpan de Juarez, Estado de Mexico, Mexico, 53370",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.4742678",
                "long": "-99.21819029999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-13",
                "contactName": "Jafra Online",
                "emailClient": "",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "DIPLOMATICOS No 41 , ACULCO, IZTAPALAPA, IZTAPALAPA, CIUDAD DE MEXICO, Mexico, 09410",
                "latitud": "20.0985989",
                "longitud": "-99.82758609999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "958516128",
                "trackingid": "b73d7617-bd1b-4469-a967-c8f8a495628d",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Se recolecta con: Miguel Eduardo Almanza Nochebuena | Entregar a: Miguel Eduardo Almanza Nochebuena | Cobro: No | Notas: Referencia:. Recibe:Miguel Eduardo Almanza Nochebuena",
                "company": "Fondeadora",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Francisco Martín del Campo  9   , Colonial Iztapalapa, Iztapalapa, Ciudad de México, Ciudad de México, Mexico, 09270",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.3442664",
                "long": "-99.05680509999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-16",
                "contactName": "Miguel Eduardo Almanza Nochebuena",
                "emailClient": "almanzamiguele@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "Francisco Martín del Campo  9   , Colonial Iztapalapa, Iztapalapa, Ciudad de México, Ciudad de México, Mexico, 09270",
                "latitud": "19.3442664",
                "longitud": "-99.05680509999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "4445719110",
                "trackingid": "f2df5146-4d72-4b6b-ad8e-19a64d74b9da",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden: 28222970611 | Se recolecta con: MIGUEL ANGEL RIVERA ESTRADA | Entregar a: Quetzali Alondra Lopez Farelas | Cobro: No | Prueba: No",
                "company": "Mercado Libre",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Av. Ayotl SN, Colonia Axotlan, Estado De México, Estado De México, Mexico, 54715",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.7007658",
                "long": "-99.2243971"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-16",
                "contactName": "Quetzali Alondra Lopez Farelas",
                "emailClient": "qlopez.xt8z1p@mail.mercadolibre.com.mx",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "Avenida Universidad SN, la mojonera, Cuernavaca, Morelos, Morelos, Mexico, 62137",
                "latitud": "18.974141",
                "longitud": "-99.246189"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "197464836",
                "trackingid": "44c5c31d-5051-41b6-bb50-daab31f2a6e1",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Se recolecta con: GRUPO MODELO S.A. DE C.V. / CE | Entregar a: WOLFGANG JULIAN ARCE HOCHSTRAS | Cobro: No | Mismo dia bike",
                "company": "Grupo Venders",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Blvd Benito Juarez No 10, Bode , San Mateo Cuautepec, San Mateo Cuautepec, MX-MEX, Mexico, 54948",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.6319351",
                "long": "-99.14951769999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "Jafra Online",
                "emailClient": "",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "RETORNO 8 NICOLAS LEON 33 , JARDIN BALBUENA, CIUDAD DE MEXICO, MX-CMX, Mexico, 15900",
                "latitud": "19.4166161",
                "longitud": "-99.1101339"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "892981056",
                "trackingid": "75f53591-bedd-46be-961c-91ffd546d3fd",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "#id | Cobro: Si, cobrar: 0.0 |  Recibe: Manuel Valdespino | Recolecta con: Juan Perez | Mismo dia bike",
                "company": "Grupo Venders",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "Calle Siempre Viva #1   Morelos  Cuauhtemoc MX-CMX 06200 Mexico, ,,06200,Mexico",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "18.6813049",
                "long": "-99.1013498"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-02-10",
                "contactName": "Manuel Valdespino",
                "emailClient": "manuel.valdespino.mx@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "5543543534",
                "address": "Domicilio Conocido S/N   Consejo Agrarista Mexicano  Iztapalapa MX-CMX 09760 Mexico, ,,09760,Mexico",
                "latitud": "19.323728",
                "longitud": "-99.05657500000001"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "1124108908",
                "trackingid": "e9de5287-5089-4be3-86b9-10385e92dcb3",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden: 6db2213b-3d11-4b19-a05c-2ae495151d40 | Se recolecta con: JORGE GARZA | Entregar a: Luis Amaya | Cobro: No | ORDER_ID_2050985, Recoger el dia: 2020-01-06, Telefono Remitente: 5551726456, entre calles: Int Ninguno Casa Blanca con puerta, referencia exterior: ORDER IDSTORE 72025",
                "company": "Envioclick ",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currenStatus": "1"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "CANTERA 51 , SANTA URSULA XITLA, Tlalpan, Tlalpan, DISTRITO FEDERAL, Mexico, 14420",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.2806041",
                "long": "-99.182071"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-03",
                "contactName": "Jafra Online",
                "emailClient": "",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "ATEPEHUACAN 28 , San Bartolo Atepehuacan, Gustavo A Madero, Gustavo A Madero, DISTRITO FEDERAL, Mexico, 07730",
                "latitud": "19.4975304",
                "longitud": "-99.14697729999999"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "424301948",
                "trackingid": "e07e2b32-a208-464f-9594-013f40f29ffd",
                "deliveryType": "SameDay",
                "notes": "#id | Cobro: Si, cobrar: 30 | Recibe: Pedro Salas | Recolecta con: Fernando Lopez",
                "company": "PRUEBAS OMITIR 99 MINUTOS STC",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 30.0,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "merida 238 cmd , 06700,40,,06700,MEX",
                "phoneSender": "5518765128",
                "lat": "19.4129603",
                "long": "-99.1557232"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-03-18",
                "contactName": "Pedro Salas",
                "emailClient": "guillermo_hard@hotmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "5518755128",
                "address": "merida 238 , roma norte 06700,238,,06700,MEX",
                "latitud": "19.4129603",
                "longitud": "-99.1557232"
            }
        },
        {
            "order": {
                "counter": "8091720766",
                "trackingid": "a18d6f56-5c41-4330-b6d9-37bc9b5a049d",
                "deliveryType": "NextDay",
                "notes": "Orden : A0212923 | Se recolecta con : VirginMobile | Entregara : MARCOS LÓPEZ GONZÁLEZ | Cobro : Si | Producto : Portabilidad | Cantidad : 1 | Transacction Id : B2C202001180179591 | Referencia : ENTRE EMILIO BALLI Y AV. TELECOMUNICACIONES.   ENFRENTE DE CORRALON DE MOTOS 39 | Monto a cobrar : 0.02 ",
                "company": "Virgin Mobile",
                "recolect": true,
                "amount": 0.02,
                "currenStatus": "3"
            },
            "pickUp": {
                "addressDestination": "av.3 88  , Unidad Ejército Constitucionalista, Ciudad de México, Distrito Federal, Mexico, 09220",
                "phoneSender": "",
                "lat": "19.3861307",
                "long": "-99.04379159999999"
            },
            "delivery": {
                "scheduledAt": "2020-01-17",
                "contactName": "MARCOS LÓPEZ GONZÁLEZ",
                "emailClient": "lgniks@gmail.com",
                "phoneClient": "None",
                "address": "av.3 88  , Unidad Ejército Constitucionalista, Ciudad de México, Distrito Federal, Mexico, 09220",
                "latitud": "19.3861307",
                "longitud": "-99.04379159999999"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I have to display these data in a recyclerview, field "message" and its subsequent fields apparently must be invoked once and the field "deliveries" contains an array of nested arrays inside; fields "order", "pickUp" and "delivery are part of a position inside an array of "deliveries".

I'm using GSON library and retrofit for do callings, in my Objects I have following:

```
data class ResponseAssign(

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message : Message? = null
```

)

This class supports "message" calling from server and the next in order of JSON array

```
data class Message(

    @field:SerializedName("AmountTotal")
    val amountTotal: Double? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("dateCort")
    val dateCort: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("deliveries")
    val deliveries: List<DeliveriesItem?>? = null
    )
```

This class supports the List of "deliveries" field in val deliveries

```
data class DeliveriesItem(

@field:SerializedName("delivery")
val delivery: Delivery? = null,

@field:SerializedName("pickUp")
val pickUp: PickUp? = null,

@field:SerializedName("order")
val order: Order? = null
)
```

and inside this class "DeliveriesItem" we have the fields of each array inside "deliveries" field as follow

```
data class Delivery(

@field:SerializedName("latitud")
val latitud: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("longitud")
val longitud: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("address")
val address: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("emailClient")
val emailClient: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("contactName")
val contactName: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("phoneClient")
val phoneClient: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("scheduledAt")
val scheduledAt: String? = null
)



data class PickUp(

@field:SerializedName("addressDestination")
val addressDestination: String? = null
)


data class Order(

@field:SerializedName("recolect")
val recolect: Boolean? = null,

@field:SerializedName("currentStatus")
val currenStatus: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("amount")
val amount: Double? = null,

@field:SerializedName("notes")
val notes: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("deliveryType")
val deliveryType: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("company")
val company: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("counter")
val counter: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("trackingid")
val trackingid: String? = null
)
```

In fragment where I invoke the recyclerview I have the following function where I'm calling the recyclerview that is overrided:

```
   override fun sendAssignOrder(responseAssign: ResponseAssign) {
  Log.d("onResponseDataOrder", responseAssign.toString())



}
```

the object ResponseAssign comes from its class as follow:

```
data class ResponseAssign(

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message : Message? = null
    )
```

One of the problems is I have to include the adapter of recyclerview in this function through a list but the function only gets a responseAssign and this is not a List this just comes as a "message" and obviously in my adapter I have to access to message members as a list to display them in a recyclerview, this is the adapter:

```
class OrderAssignAdapter(val items : List<DeliveriesItem>, view: View, contexto: Context, bundler : Bundle): RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAssignAdapter.AssignViewAdapter>() {

private var filterListResult : List<DeliveriesItem> = items
private var vista : View = view
private var bundle : Bundle = bundler
private var context : Context = contexto



class AssignViewAdapter(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var textCompany : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcompany)
    var textDirEntrega : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDirentrega)
    var textClaveRastreo : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtclaveRastreo)
    var textTipoEntrega : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttipoentrega)
    var textMonto : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtmonto)
    var textStatus : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtstatus)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p0: Int): AssignViewAdapter {

    val vista : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_orden,parent,false)
    val layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    vista.layoutParams=layoutParams
    return AssignViewAdapter(vista)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return filterListResult.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AssignViewAdapter, position: Int) {

    /*holder.textCompany.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.order?.get(position)?.company?.get(position).toString()
    holder.textDirEntrega.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.delivery?.get(position)?.address?.get(position).toString()
    holder.textClaveRastreo.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.order?.get(position)?.trackingid?.get(position).toString()
    holder.textTipoEntrega.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.order?.get(position)?.deliveryType?.get(position).toString()
    holder.textMonto.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.order?.get(position)?.amount.toString()
    holder.textStatus.text = filterListResult[position].deliveries?.get(position)?.order?.get(position)?.currenStatus?.get(position).toString()*/


}
}
```

If someone can help me with this issue, I will be grateful, hopefully

Best Regards

Sorry for my bad english, I hope to have explained well

Comment: Do you want to show DeliveriesItem in RecyclerView?

Comment: Yeah, but this array is inside Message class as you can see

Comment: You can get items `responseAssign.messages.deliveries` and set this list to `RecyclerView`

Comment: @ysfcyln directly in the function of adapter?

Comment: Yes, create new adapter like `new OrderAssignAdapter(responseAssign.messages.deliveries, view, context, bundle)` and set it to recyclerview